# How to fade one react component out, then fade another in?

Tags: react-transition-group

I've got 2 components that are conditionally shown or hidden based on a string value stored in useState as `showModal`

```
{showModal === 'SIGNIN' && <SignIn />}
{showModal === 'JOIN' && <Join />}
```

I want to fade in one component, then when the state changes, fade it out and fade in the other component.

Can this be done with `react transition group`?

I tried

```
<TransitionGroup>
    <CSSTransition in={showModal === 'SIGNIN' ? true : false} classNames='fade' timeout={220} key={showModal}>
       <div> 
          <SignIn />
       </div>
     </CSSTransition>
     <CSSTransition in={showModal === 'JOIN' ? true : false} classNames='fade' timeout={220} key={showModal}>
       <div> 
         <Join />
       </div>
     </CSSTransition>
</TransitionGroup>
```

I don't get any error, one component is shown, changing showModal from 'SIGNIN' to 'JOIN' does nothing. Inspecting the divs with the timeout set to 22000 shows that no new classes have been added.

Comment: You may need to wrap each inner component in its own `CSSTransition` component. I'm new to them myself, though.

Comment: Looks like that's the case: http://reactcommunity.org/react-transition-group/transition-group#TransitionGroup-prop-children

Comment: yes this example maps over an array and then animates items going in and out of the array, I don't have an array, I just got 2 components

Comment: I wonder if that error isn't just a long-winded way of telling you you're missing [props](http://reactcommunity.org/react-transition-group/css-transition) on `CSSTransition`. In my one implementation I used the state value in an `in` property. What are you doing for that?

Comment: thanks again, I've updated the question to show the attempt at using the `in`

Answer (score 1):

[SwitchTransition](http://reactcommunity.org/react-transition-group/switch-transition) from `react transition group` might help.

**Example**

```js
const { useState, useEffect } = React;
const { SwitchTransition, CSSTransition } = ReactTransitionGroup;

const SignIn = () => <div className="block sign-in">Sign In</div>;

const Join = () => <div className="block join">Join</div>;

const App = () => {
const [showModal, setModal] = useState("SIGNIN");

  useEffect(() => {
      let handle;
      
      const loop = () => {
      
        setModal(state => state === "JOIN" ? "SIGNIN" : "JOIN");
      
        handle = setTimeout(loop, 2500);
      };
  
      handle = setTimeout(loop, 1000);
      
      return () => {
        clearTimeout(handle);
      }
  }, []);
  
  const addEndListener = (node, done) => {
              node.addEventListener("transitionend", done, false);
            }

return <div>
  <SwitchTransition mode="out-in">
    <CSSTransition
      key={showModal === "SIGNIN"}
      addEndListener={addEndListener}
      classNames="fade">
        {showModal === "SIGNIN" ? <SignIn/> : <Join/>}
  </CSSTransition>
</SwitchTransition>
</div>;
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <App />,
    document.getElementById('root')
  );
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  font-family: Georgia, serif;
}

.block {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  padding: 10px;
  color: white;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 30px;
}

.sign-in { 
  background: #0984e3;
}

.join {
  background: #6c5ce7;
}

.fade-enter {
   opacity: 0;
    transform: translate(-100%, -50%);
}

.fade-exit {
   opacity: 1;
   transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.fade-enter-active {
   opacity: 1;
   transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.fade-exit-active {
   opacity: 0;
   transform: translate(100%, -50%);
}

.fade-enter-active,
.fade-exit-active {
   transition: opacity 500ms, transform 500ms;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-transition-group@4.4.2
/dist/react-transition-group.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6/babel.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: thank you for this great looking answer, ill be checking it out this evening for sure! Thanks again!